# Parse Cloud Code: Error: code = 107, "Received an error with invalid JSON from Parse: Cannot POST /parse/classes/Event"; }

Tags: ios, json, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to successfully get data from a MongoDB Parse database using cloud code implemented in Swift.  I am receiving an error code: [Error]: {
    code = 107;
    message = "Received an error with invalid JSON from Parse: Cannot POST /parse/classes/Event";
} (Code: 141, Version: 1.13.0)

Here is my server code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('function1', function(request, response) {  
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var event = Parse.Object.extend("Event");
    var query = new Parse.Query(event);
    query.first({
      success: function(object) {
     reponse.success("hey");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error(error);
    }
    });
});
```

Here is my Swift code:

```
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("function1", withParameters: []) { (result:AnyObject?, error:NSError?) in
        print("result: ")
        print(result)
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Also result is printing as nil.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: There are still a number of things that can go wrong here. Since I have not done a lot of Mongo and nor Parse so far a lot of this will be guesswork, but since you did not provide it ... First of all why do you respond with `"hey"` in your `success` case? Should that not be `object`? Or should you not at least log `object` on the server in the `success` case in order to be able to tell us how it looks? On the other hand you should try hard to figure out a way to show us the "raw" response string from your call. Are you sure you actually get through to the server by the way? More info please.